# Not working, string in android when making Post request with Json Object

Tags: java, php, android, json, string

I have a problem that I havent been able to solve, I am connecting my Android app to a Laravel API, everything is working well, but when I try to send the JsonObject for the Post request it returns a 500 (I know 500 is an error of the server side, but Dingo likes to throw that code).
The problem is, I just get this error when sending the JsonObject with the String variable names, but when I send the literal String, everything works fine. Ive already tried encoding to UTF-8. What could it be? I will leave my code below.

This way it works:

private void authorizeClient(String name, String secret, String ID){

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try{
        String secretFinal = URLEncoder.encode(secret, "UTF-8");
        jsonObject.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        jsonObject.put("name", name);
        jsonObject.put("client_secret", "c3melO2KvDQ:APA91bHYvSUJsSkB3dOKwk8zfgG0");
        jsonObject.put("client_id","287cdh27ldns7isvw7e3sd47ngau37t449123456");
```

This way it doesnt work:

private void authorizeClient(String name, String secret, String ID){

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try{
        String secretFinal = URLEncoder.encode(secret, "UTF-8");
        jsonObject.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        jsonObject.put("name", name);
        jsonObject.put("client_secret", secret);
        jsonObject.put("client_id",ID);
```

Comment: You are not using secretFinal in the second code snippet. Is that the reason why it does not work?

Comment: I tried it both with secret, secretFinal. Also I tries exchanging the String one by one, the name string works fine, but the secret and the id dont. I dont know if it has something to do with the simbols it has or the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, its all fixed. It was the lenght of the String that the database would not allow. I fixed it by making a substring.